# catch22: Needing to remove redirect chain I seem to need

Tags: .htaccess

I've been using paths like

`<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/directory/file.php'); ?>`

in my pages, and it works as expected.  However, when I run speed tests with sites like GTmetrix, they all complain about redirects.  For example:

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
h-t-t-p://mysite.com/directory/images/shorter.png
h-t-t-p://www.mysite.com/directory/images/shorter.png
```

I suppose this is due to these lines in my main .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So it seems I have a catch22 here.  The search engines don't want my site to appear to have duplicate content, and the redirect is a factor in slowing things down.

What is the best practice here?  It seems a common situation, but I can't find any solutions by Googling.  Should I redefine document_root, so the redirect at the registrar level, or what?

Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Comment: Modified this post since the document_root part didn't show up when I first posted, which made the original question unclear

Answer (score 0):

Avoid unnecessary static content redirects by updating the `src` and `href` attributes in your HTML to use the full domain name including the `www`.

Or, use absolute paths without the domain name at all.

Or, add a rule to exclude some types of files:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|gif|jpeg|png|jpg|pdf|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your answer made sense the way my question was displayed.  Now that I have edited it so all of my question appears, how would I do this?

Comment: @Janie your updates don't change my answer... Have you tried my rule to ignore certain file types? Have you updated your HTML to always contain the `www`?

Comment: I don't use http:  or www in my html.  I either use relative paths or absolute paths.